# Null object reference in setText

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
Location one = null;
Location two = null;
float dystans = 0;

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(MainActivity.running && MainActivity.x == 0){
        one = location;
        MainActivity.x = 1;
    }
    else if(MainActivity.running && MainActivity.x == 1){
        two = location;
        dystans = dystans + two.distanceTo(one);
        MainActivity.kilometry.setText(Float.toString(dystans));
        one = two;
    }
}
```

And this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I have no idea why there's null, I think there shouldn't be null, because location in onLocationChanged is never Null, so "dystans" can't be Null too

Comment: kilometry is null, what's the id of kilometry in xml?

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.kilometry is the null reference the error is talking about, not dystans.